# Are flatlanders stuck in 2D?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, 2d

A 3D creature "Boo" decides to visit flatland for a vacation.There he becomes friend with a flatlander "Elo" .They talk, eat and enjoy (don't ask how). While leaving Boo tells Elo about his world and how bizarre his 3D world is compared to this 2D world; greatly astonished Elo asks if he too can experience that reality.So how can Poo manage to do this given Elo has absolutely no 3rd dimensional component like the thinnest(imaginary) paper with absolutely 0 thickness.Wouldn't Poo will simply pass through Elo's body if he ever tries to lift him "up"?

I came to think about it while watching [Carl Sagan explain about dimensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0WjV6MmCyM) .

Comment: wouldn't be faster if you get a copy of Abbott's Flatland and read it?

Comment: [*Flatland* can be found on Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/97) along with many fine books.

Comment: VTCers should give an explanation for their close votes.  I'm not convinced this question should be closed, though it could use a bit more thought.  Only a slice of your 3D Boo can exist in flatland.  Which slice would be capable of communicating with Elo?  If Elo were lifted out of flatland, he would still perceive only a slice of wherever he went (not unlike our perception of time one moment-at-a-time).

Comment: @L.Dutch I never knew about it.Read just wiki page sounds very interesting I am guessing this would narrative based kinda similar to "The time machine" by HG. Wells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No two dimensional (physical) object can exist in a three (or greater) dimensional world. The uncertainty principle guarantees this. A perfectly 2D object would have zero position uncertainty in the third direction and that means it would have infinite momentum uncertainty. This means:

1. it would take infinite energy to confine the object to be exactly two dimensional
2. the object would expand back into the third dimension infinitely quickly

It is certainly possible to have objects so thin that they appear to be two dimensional. Graphene is an obvious example. But objects of this type are three dimensional and interact with other three dimensional objects in the usual way. Unless there is some mechanism to confine them they would be free to move in the third dimension just like everything else.

An example of such a confining mechanism might be something along the lines of the [brane world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) idea. This confines the ends of strings to a 3D brane even though the strings themselves remain nine dimensional.

Comment: Interesting use of the uncertainty principle.

Comment: @StephenG Your use of the word *interesting* worries me :-)

Comment: I mean that the point had not occurred to me, as obvious as it may have been to you. :-)